# Caching on UIWebView and Google Chrome -Weird

Tags: ios, caching, google-chrome, uiwebview

I have 2 PHP files. One for inserting data into a database and the other to display the data.

For a long time, I was facing a delay between display time and insertion time. I then realized it was due to caching by Google Chrome.

To prevent browser caching, I added the following lines of code to the PHP file doing the display work:

```
<META http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

This did not solve the problem. What worked was disabling the Chrome Cache manually. (Ctrl+Shift+i and then checking "disable cache"). Doing this, I was able to see the freshly inserted data instantaneously.

Now, in my iOS application, I have added a UIWebView and face a similar problem. Because of caching, there is a long gap between display and insertion.

To prevent caching in the UIWebView I tried the following:

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

While loading the display webpage, I used a request with a cachePolicy: `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData`.

All of my attempts were futile as nothing worked.

What I do not understand, however, is that when I keep the display webpage switched on, on the Chrome (disabled cache), the display webpage on the UIWebView is instantaneously updated.

It'd be great if you could explain as to why this happens and how I can solve this caching problem on the UIWebView.

Comment: If you get different results when Chrome is viewing the webpage than when it's not, that's probably a problem on your server. You also might want to make sure the <meta> tags are in the <head> section of your webpage.